# Flutter AES128 encryption not matching with java and angular AES encryption

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, aes

I have to implement a dart algorithm in order to encrypt a password and send it to a server for authentication from a flutter app (it's barely a week since I'm on flutter/dart). This has already been implemented in an android app and angular web app (not from me), which both produce the same encrypted password even though with different algorithms.

Java code for android:

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.CryptoPrimitive;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class AesUtil {
    private final int keySize;
    private final int iterationCount;
    private final Cipher cipher;

    public AesUtil(int keySize, int iterationCount) {
        this.keySize = keySize;
        this.iterationCount = iterationCount;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw fail(e);
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(String salt, String iv, String passphrase, String ciphertext) {
        try {
            SecretKey key = generateKey(salt, passphrase);
            byte[] decrypted = doFinal(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv, base64(ciphertext));
            return new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private byte[] doFinal(int encryptMode, SecretKey key, String iv, byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            cipher.init(encryptMode, key, new IvParameterSpec(hex(iv)));
            return cipher.doFinal(bytes);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException
                | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                | IllegalBlockSizeException
                | BadPaddingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private SecretKey generateKey(String salt, String passphrase) {
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), hex(salt), iterationCount, keySize);
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
            return key;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] base64(String str) {
        return Base64.decode(str);
    }

    public static String base64(byte[] bytes) {
        return new String(Base64.encode(bytes));
    }

    public static byte[] hex(String str) {
        try {
            return Hex.decode(str);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String hex(byte[] bytes) {
        return Hex.encode(bytes).toString();
    }

    private IllegalStateException fail(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }


    public String random(int length) {
        byte[] salt = new byte[length];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);
        return hex(salt);
    }

    public String encrypt(String salt, String iv, String passphrase, String plaintext) {
        try {
            SecretKey key = generateKey(salt, passphrase);
            byte[] encrypted = doFinal(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv, plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));


            return base64(encrypted);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw fail(e);
        }
    }

    public String encriptToAES(String password) {
        //`
        //for some reasons key, iv and salt are hardcoded string
        //
        final String key = "hardcoded_key_16_characters";
         
        final String iv = "hardcoded_iv_32_characters";
        final String salt = "hardcoded_salt_32_characters";
        String ciphertext = encrypt(salt, iv, key, password);

        String preEncr = new String(Base64.encode((iv + "::" + salt + "::" + ciphertext).getBytes()));
        return preEncr;
    }
}
```

And this is the java line of code which generate the encrypted password:
AesUtil(128, 1000).encriptToAES(password)

JS code for angular:

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

export class AesUtil{
private keySize;
private iterationCount;
  constructor(keySize, iterationCount) {
    this.keySize = keySize / 32;
    this.iterationCount = iterationCount;
  };
  
  generateKey(salt, passPhrase) {
    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(
        passPhrase, 
        CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt),
        { keySize: this.keySize, iterations: this.iterationCount });
    return key;
  }
  
  encrypt(salt, iv, passPhrase, plainText) {
    var key = this.generateKey(salt, passPhrase);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        plainText,
        key,
        { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv) });
    return encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
  }
  
  decrypt(salt, iv, passPhrase, cipherText) {
    var key = this.generateKey(salt, passPhrase);
    var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
      ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(cipherText)
    });
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        cipherParams,
        key,
        { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv) });
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }
}
```

And this code does the trick:

```
const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

const aesUtil = newAesUtil(128,1000);
const cipherText = aesUtils.encrypt(salt,iv,'hardcoded_key_16_characters',password);
const aesPassword = (iv+ '::' + salt + '::'+ cipherText);
const encryptedPassword = btoa(aesPassword);
```

For what I can understand I need an AES128 encryption method, where to set a specific number of iterations, which accepts iv and salt and eventually encrypt the result with Base64.

I have already tried all kinds of dart encryption packages on pub.dev and snippets without success.

I was relying on [this](https://gist.github.com/suehok/dfc4a6989537e4a3ba4058669289737f#file-cryptojs_aes_encryption_helper-dart) one in particular, but even with hardcoded parameters the result password doesn't match and I'm not able to figure out why. Does anyone know on which elements I have to focus in order to achieve the same result in flutter? For example, which aes128 'plugin' should I use? Static or random iv and salt? All kind of things, I'm pretty much lost. Thanks

UPDATE:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cryptography/cryptography.dart';

final password = "justatest";
final key = "0123456789abcdef";
final iv = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv";
final salt = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyz012345";

encryptAESCryptoJS() {
  final pbkdf2 = Pbkdf2(
    macAlgorithm: Hmac(sha1),
    iterations: 1000,
    bits: 128,
  );

  final Uint8List hashBytes = pbkdf2.deriveBitsSync(
    utf8.encode(key),
    nonce: Nonce(utf8.encode(salt)),
  );

}
```

Comment: Both posted codes apply AES in CBC mode and PKCS7 padding. The key is derived from a salt, password and iteration count (note 100 in JS, 1000 in Java, probably a typo) using PBKDF2 (with HMAC/SHA1) as algorithm. Salt and IV are specified explicitly (in JS randomly generated). It seems that in the linked code no PBKDF2 is used, so you have to find a PBKDF2 implementation for Dart, e.g. this [one](https://pub.dev/documentation/cryptography/latest/cryptography/Pbkdf2-class.html) (not tested). For a more concrete support post your dart code please.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Yes, it was a typo, the correct iteration count it's 1000.
I don't really have code to show right now because I'm still trying to put these things together. 
As you can imagine I'm really not familiar with encryption so I'm copying snippets, trying to make some changes, deleting all when it doesn't work to start with something else.
So, first of all, I'm trying to cipher the key with the PBKDF2 with the package you pointed out but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right (the "nonce" part especially) and how to handle the "hashBytes". I've pasted some dart code about it

Comment: The input of PBKDF2 is password, salt and iteration count (and also the desired key size). The key is returned. I.e. in your code `iv` and `key` are not needed for key derivation, you must `use utf8.encode(password)` instead of `utf8.encode(key)` and `hashBytes` is the derived key.

Comment: "I'm copying snippets, trying to make some changes, deleting all when it doesn't work to start with something else" You should not do that, you should lookup the relevant cryptography and learn how it works. You could be performing your changes until you pass away and not succeed.

Comment: Indeed Maarten, but since cryptography is not an "easy" topic it would require some time to fully understand it in order to solve this single (in the short term, at least) problem by myself.
And since my main goal right now is to learn flutter/dart and the time available to do it is "uncertain" I was hoping to overcome it trying to translate the working java/js code to dart with some advice from someone wich already knows the topic (or fix some "example code" to make it work at least).

Comment: But I'm not making significant progress so I guess Maarten is right. I'll hardcode a know encrypted password for now in order to go ahead with the purpose of this exercise application and return to this problem eventually. Thank you Topaco for your kind help